# iOS - UITableViewCell, UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uitableview

Good day to all. Faced a problem. I need to make a table with a button and by clicking on the button I get a alert with the number of the cell. The table cells themselves are not active. That's how I realized it. When I scroll the table in the beginning everything is fine, when you press the button, a alert is displayed with the correct line number, but  after 4 elements an error appears.

This error appears in the line where I'm working with the 4 tag.
Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        let numLabel: UILabel = tableView.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        numLabel.text = String(indexPath.row)
    } else if (tableView.tag == 2) {

        //Error appears here
        let numButton: UIButton = tableView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton 
        numButton.setTitle(String(indexPath.row), for: .normal)

        numButton.tag = indexPath.row
    }

    return cell
}

@IBAction func showAlertForRow(row: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Test work",message:"Cell at row \(row.tag) was tapped!",preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This is because the UIButton with tag 4 isn't available anymore once it's out of the screen. This approach feels wrong, create a custom cell for this.

Comment: what is this `tableView.viewWithTag(3)` Where you have added subviews inside tableview ?, There should be cell if i am not wrong

Comment: I have two table in one view controller. There are labels in the first table. I gave tag number for my element. First table - 1, second table - 2, label from first table - 3 and button from second table - 4.  
Maybe I should do it  with- optional binding? But I do not understand what to write in else case?

Comment: `if (tableView.tag == 1) {
            let numLabel: UILabel = tableView.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
            numLabel.text = String(indexPath.row)
        } else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
            
            if let numButton: UIButton = tableView.viewWithTag(4) as? UIButton {
            numButton.setTitle(String(indexPath.row), for: .normal)
            numButton.tag = indexPath.row
            } else {
                
            }
        }`

Comment: @Crowl: if the answer is helpful hope you'll accept it. :)

Comment: Thank you so much @elk_cloner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are designing for implementing this procedure is not correct. What you can do

1. Make a custom cell
2. Add a button in custom cell
3. Add action in that button in CellForRowAtIndexPath
4. Handle action from ViewController where you added tableView.

I made a whole project for you.Just to let you know. if you want to add customCell in tableView you need to register it like this in viewDidLoad.
i have done is in **ViewController.swift** file. check out my project.

```
let nib = UINib.init(nibName:String(describing: sampleTableViewCell.self) , bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "chatCell")
```

Then check cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatCell", for: indexPath) as! sampleTableViewCell

    cell.clickMeBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.clickMeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onButtonPressed(sender :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell

}
```

Button press function:

```
func onButtonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title:"Cell index is"+String(sender.tag), message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (UIAlertAction) in

    }

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Check only three files:

[Github link](https://github.com/junaid4058/tableViewButtonCell/upload)

1. ViewController.swift
2. sampleTableViewCell.swift
3. sampleTableViewCell.xib**

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: This is how it should be done, try to follow the same as best practice @Crowl

Comment: Thank you so much @elk_cloner